# SWIG Python binding seems empty

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have the following files for generating a Python binding to a C++ project with SWIG and CMake:

**test.h**

```
int add(int a, int b);
```

**test.cpp**

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
        return a+b;
}
```

**test.i**

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(swig-test)

# This is a CMake example for Python

add_library(testcpp SHARED test.cpp)

FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(test.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(test.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")
set(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC")
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(test python test.i)
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(test testcpp)
```

It compiles successfully and `libtestcpp.so`, `_test.so`, and `test.py` are created. `strings libtestcpp.so` and `strings _test.so` both have an entry `_Z3addii` and `import test` works in Python, but there is nothing under the `test` namespace in Python.

I've also tried manually compiling with

```
swig -c++ -python test.i
g++ -c -fpic test.cpp test_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I.
g++ -shared test.o test_wrap.o -o _test.so
```

with the same result.

It may be useful to note that `import test` isn't a *completely* empty module; `import test; dir(test)` yields

```
['__builtin__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '_newclass',
 '_object',
 '_swig_getattr',
 '_swig_property',
 '_swig_repr',
 '_swig_setattr',
 '_swig_setattr_nondynamic',
 '_test']
```

and `import test; help(test)` has a description that it is created by SWIG.

Comment: I think you still need to add a line `%include "test.h"` at the end in `test.i`.

Comment: That is indeed correct  -- I seem to have completely overlooked that!

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure before I commented. I converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to to add a line `%include "test.h"` at the end in test.i

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"
```